# ProgrammingError: Syntax issue with MySQL query using + INTERVAL 14 DAY

Tags: python-3.x, spyder, mysql-connector

I am working on a **library automation system using Python and MySQL.** In my Python script, I have the following MySQL query to create a table for loans:

```
cur.execute("""
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Loans (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    book_id INT,
    member_id INT,
    issue_date DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    due_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 14 DAY,
    FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES Books(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (member_id) REFERENCES Members(id)
)""")
```

However, when I execute this, **I encounter the following error:**

```
ProgrammingError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+ INTERVAL 14 DAY, FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES Books(id), ...
```

I have checked the MySQL documentation, and the syntax seems correct.  Is there anything obvious that I am missing in the syntax or is there a compatibility issue with my MySQL version?

**Additional Information:**

• MySQL Server Version:8.0.34

• MySQL Connector Version:8.2.0

• Python Version: 3.9.12 (main, Apr  4 2022, 05:22:27)